# Service file is not giving permission to required files

Tags: python, azure, service, systemd, azure-iot-edge

I am executing a Python script through service file. The python script is responsible to create 3 more scripts and then execute them one by one. I am also giving permission to all of them and also to a folder in my home directory.
The problem here is that on executing the service file none of the Python files or the folder is getting the permissions. I am giving 777 permission
Following is my service file

```
[Unit] 
Description=systemd service to run upload script 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=jetson
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/project/file_upload.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The folder I am trying to give permission to is created by the azure Iotedge module
Please let me know if I need to make any changes in the service file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating the folder before starting the service file and gave it permission so now there are no issues.